# How does Object A wait for Object B to complete getting location data in its Core Location Delegate, so it can use the data?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, core-location

- Object A calls Object B to start Core Location and acquire location data.
- Object B is also the Core Location Delegate and receives a successful callback, data is received.
- Object B's delegate stops Core Location as only one location data point is needed.
- Object A wants to use that location data, and does have access to the location variables in Object B

The problem is that Object A tries to use those empty variables before Object B has acquired the Core Location data. Object A races on, Object's B's Core Location data is not yet available.

How does Object A effectively "wait", or get notified that the data is there and its ok to proceed ?

Thanks, Ric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way, [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

In Object B header file:

```
extern NSString *const kLocationKey;
extern NSString *const kIGotLocationNotification; // whatever name you like
```

In Object B implementation file:

```
// assign a string we will use for the notification center
NSString *const kIGotLocationNotification = @"Any text you like here";
NSString *const kLocationKey = @"Location";


// in the method where you stop core location
CLLocation *loc;

// create a dictionary object with the location info
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:loc forKey:kLocationKey];

// you post a notification to the default center
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kIGotLocationNotification object:self userInfo:dict];
```

In Object A implementation file:

```
// inside your init method 
// become an observer with the default center
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleIGotLocation:) name:kIGotLocationNotification object:nil];

// inside your dealloc
// don't forget to remove yourself from the notification default center
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];


// create the selector that will receive the notification
- (void)handleIGotLocation:(NSNotification *)pNotification {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", [pNotification name]);
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", [pNotification object]);

    // the user info is going to contain the dict with your location
    NSLog(@"UserInfo: %@", [pNotification userInfo]);
}
```

Comment: The idea of using NSNotificationCenter works if I have Object A's code being a View Controller, where it comes to rest in a system run loop. I had actually put Object A's code in the App Delegate's ApplicationDidFinishLaunching, but the problem there is that it does not come to rest, it continues running to the end of the method.  No opportunity to wait for the notification.  I'll have to rethink where Object A's code operates from.

Comment: You lost me.  What method is running the end?  Post the method you are talking about in your question.

Comment: Well the code that wants to use the Loc data is in the AppDidFinishLaunching.  That code method waits for nobody, it will run to its end (of the method).  There is not way to halt and wait for a loc data to come available there. I have to rethink where this Core Location code is being requested.

Comment: No, you don't want to wait in AppDidFinishLaunching.  Like you said, you will have to rethink your Core Location code.  Maybe use a flag to indicate you have the location.  And any code that requires location can check the flag to see if it's YES.